# Trying to insert geovalue in Postgresql but it shows syntax error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, jsonparser, google-trends

I want  to insert the geovalue in PostgreSQL but it shows some kind of syntax error.

```
 try {

        var res = await googleTrends.interestByRegion({keyword:keyword,geo:"US-"+state}); //resolution:keyword
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        // for debugging.
        //console.log(res);
        if("default" in res){
          if("geoMapData" in res["default"]){
            for(var x in res["default"].geoMapData){
              var row = res["default"].geoMapData[x];

              if("geoName" in row && "value" in row){
              // console.log(" - " + row.geoName + "\t\t" + row.value);
                console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",x,row.value)

                  //insert statement
                  var name1 = [row.value]
                //    name1.push([keyword,row.geoName])
                // var name2 = [row.geoName]

                   pool.query("INSERT INTO value(id) VALUES($1)",name1,(err, res) => {
                        console.log(err, res);
                      //   pool.end(() => {

                        //        console.log('pool has ended')
                          //})
                    });

            }   
              else{
                console.log("Invalid row, missing fields.");
              }

            }

          }else{
            console.log("Malformed JSON result, geoMapData missing.");
          }
        }else{
          console.log("Malformed JSON result, default missing");
        }

      }catch(e){
        console.log("Failed:" + e);
      }

    }


  }

}
(async() => {
  await main();
})();
```

These are the error i'm getting

error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{"93"}"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/abc/Desktop/node2/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/abc/Desktop/node2/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:403:19)
    at Socket. (/home/abc/Desktop/node2/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:22)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the square brackets from the array declaration
var name1 = [row.value]